# VIM problems with erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, erb

Whenever I make a open or save and erb file. I get this error. No idea how to fix it

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>59_UpdateErrors..<SNR>59_CacheErrors..SyntaxCheckers_eruby_GetLocList..SyntasticMake:
Line 20:
E40: Can't open errorfile ~\AppData\Local\Temp\VIeF751.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too critical, try deleting the `~\AppData\Local\Temp\VIeF751.tmp` file. It might have gotten corrupted, and now when Vim tries to access it, it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: tried that already. the problem is it doesnt exist. The filename is randomly generated, so the 2nd time I save an erb file again, it'll say "can't open....Local\Temp\VIeD201.tmp or some other filename

Comment: Try disabling some of your vimscripts, to figure out which one is causing the problem. AppData is a Windows thing, so you might have a script that is assuming you're on Windows.